# Why doesn't my parallelize function do much?

Tags: python, parallel-processing

I'm working on a 16 core machine with each core able to run 2 jobs. I'm trying to parallelize my code to run faster but when I test the parallelize function (mostly from here: https://towardsdatascience.com/make-your-own-super-pandas-using-multiproc-1c04f41944a1) it doesn't seem to do much.

Here is my parallelize function:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import  Pool

def parallel_apply_single_col(col, func, n_splits):
    col_split = np.array_split(col, n_splits)
    pool = Pool(n_splits)
    out = pd.concat(pool.map(func, col_split))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    return(out)
```

To test it I tried the following:

```
len = 100000000
a = list(range(5, 5 + len))
b = list(range(100, 100 + len))
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': a, 'b': b})
df.shape

def add_one_helper(x):
    return('{}1'.format(x))

def add_one(col):
    return(col.apply(add_one_helper))
```

```
%%timeit
parallel_apply_single_col(df['a'], add_one, 30)
```

`29.9 s ± 370 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`

```
%%timeit
add_one(df['a'])
```

`46.1 s ± 726 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`

I'm wondering why the parallelization doesn't do too much. I know that using 30 jobs in parallel won't reduce the time by a factor of 30, but I was expecting more than a 35% improvement.

Comment: there's overhead in creating the pools and coalescing the results. you'll likely see more gains on a larger dataframe

Comment: The common misconception with parallelism is that if a function takes  time `T`, then parallel threads will make it time `T/n`. In reality theres a cost to starting the workers and joining the results, so you have time `T/n + C`. You only see gains if you have a large enough `T` such that `T < T/n + C`

Comment: Thanks @PaulH. I edited the post to show how I created my data frame. I thought it was big enough to show significant gains, but I'll try it with a bigger dataframe.

Comment: i know this is a simple case, but I bet `df[col].astype(str) + '1'` is pretty performant too

Comment: also, the `pd.concat` probably takes a while. i'd be curious to see that moved outside of your function to isolate it in your timing

Comment: You're giving the Pool `n_splits` workers. What if there is more workers than cores? You will have some overhead as the cpu can't keep up with the number of workers. This is special true if your function already cpu heavy

Comment: @PaulH the `pd.concat` is pretty minimal. Removing it took ~4 sec - maybe if I did a bigger split it would make a bigger difference but I suspect that, under he hood, concat is just doing pointer operations so its not really a lot of work.

Comment: Just to add a finisher to this - the function above provided significant savings on a dataframe with ~5.5 million records with a function doing a bunch of text pre-processing. It brought it down from well over an hour (I didn't time it last night) to ~15 min!